# What is the best method to calculate time elapsed to 1ms of accuracy in a windows system in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, datetime, winapi, time

I am working on a program in which I want to know the time elapsed between two calls down to the ms.

I was reading the windows documentation on SYSTEMTIME structure (minwinbase.h), QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime function (realtimeapiset.h), Windows time (windows.h) and it sounds like QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime is the way to go, however just curious if there is an established best method for this sort of requirement.

Additionally, is there a convenient way to compare something like a SYSTEMTIME time-object, or would the fastest / easier way just be to break down the object into hours, minutes, seconds, ms, and subtract one from the other?

Comment: I would start with [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) and see if that produced sufficient resolution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905157/how-to-print-the-execution-time-of-my-code

Comment: IMHO it is a duplicated of the downvoted question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384904/how-can-i-get-a-clock-time-accurate-to-1ms-in-windows The comment there *This isn't any more accurate than `GetLocalTime()`, and will be considerably less accurate if Windows adjusts its real time clock to match reality (which it does periodically using NTP). It is more precise however.* And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60823110/accurate-sleep-wait-windows-os-1ms-accuracy

Comment: I generally use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31905437/3807729

Comment: Windows API for measurement are explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps . But first try the `steady_clock` solution and see if it's enough.

Comment: QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime requires a minimum of Windows 7, for compatibility with earlier systems (and also for higher resolution) you can use QueryPerformanceFrequency/QueryPerformanceCounter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything windows specific to calculate this. What is important is that you need to use a steady clock instead of high_resolution_clock or system_clock (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263277/difference-between-stdsystem-clock-and-stdsteady-clock)) to understand why.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    // someFunctionThatTakesTime()
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1).count(); 

}
```

To calculate the time period between two days, you use the code in the following answer (the code calculates the days between two dates but you could cast to a different time period if you liked):

[Number of days between two dates C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218894/number-of-days-between-two-dates-c)

Comment: Stick to `std::steady_clock`. [A note on `std::high_resolution_clock` from one of the people most responsible for creating it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37440647/4581301). TL;DR version: He says "My bad."